# Python program that inserts data to PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, user-interface

**Status:**

I have a PostgreSQL database with an existing schema: basically one table whose fields are connected to other tables with keys. Hence, for some fields there is already a list of possible answers.

**Goal:**

My final goal is to create an user friendly GUI which enables "non-technical" users to insert data. My plan is to first build a Python library that can do all my required functionality and later built the GUI around it.

**Plan:**

My current idea is to create classes which correspond to the most important tables of my PostgreSQL database. Then I want to add methods to those classes like insert_data(), is_valid(), send_to_database() ... But I have the feeling, that I am recreating a structure that already exists. I know that there are libraries like [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) that might be useful.

**Question**:

Shall I recreate the existing database scheme in Python or shall I create it automatically with another library? Is there any other smart way how to approach my task?

Comment: Your plan could simply be to ask your users to download pgadmin

Comment: Check out using PonyORM - nice GUI designer and code generator.

Comment: @e4c5 pgAdmin is not user-friendly for "non-technical" users. In the end I need to have a GUI where everything can be done by clicking through drop-down menus.